# How to FindElement By Xpath in Selenium PhantomJS C#

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, xpath, phantomjs

This is the structure:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="debugTxt" style="color:blue;">Wed Jul 27 2016 10:06:12 GMT+0800 (Sample)Sample<br>
    Sample<br>
    Wed Jul 27 2016 10:06:12 GMT+0800 (Sample) Sample<br>
    Wed Jul 27 2016 10:06:12 GMT+0800 (Sample) Sample！<br>
    Wed Jul 27 2016 10:06:12 GMT+0800 (Sample) <br>
    DataTOGET：<a href="http://Please.Get.Me" target="_blank">http://Please.Get.Me</a><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
driver1.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='debugTxt']")).GetAttribute("value");
```

Is it possible to get the value of `http://Please.Get.Me` ?

Comment: Do you want visible text or href attribute value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little tweak and help from alecxe

```
driver1.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='debugTxt']//a")).GetAttribute("href");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just tweak your expression to match the `a` element inside the `div`:

```
driver1.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='debugTxt']/a")).GetAttribute("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want visible text of the link, you should try using `.Text` as below :-

```
driver1.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='debugTxt']/a")).Text;
```